Ggplot2 + geom_sankey_bump: Sort legend
i made this plot with geom_sankey_bumb and would like to sort the legend depending on the value of Name for the last data point/Year available for a better understanding of the data. Right now it's just sorted by name.
Does anybody know how to do this?
library(dplyr)
library(ggsankey)


# Variables
set.seed(123) 
years <- rep(2015:2024, each = 5)  
names <- c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "Diana", "Eve")  
values <- runif(length(years), min = 10, max = 100)  

# DataFrame
data <- data.frame(
  Year = years,
  Name = rep(names, times = length(unique(years))),
  Value = round(values, 2)  
)

data_sankey <- data %>%
  mutate(
    id = as.character(Year),  
    next_id = as.character(Name),   
    value = Value                 
  )


# define colors
anzahl_unique <- length(unique(data$Name))
nb.cols <- anzahl_unique
farben <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(12, "Set3"))(nb.cols)

p1 <- ggplot(data_sankey, aes(
  x = id,          
  next_x = next_id, 
  node = next_id,   
  fill = next_id,   
  value = value    
)) +
  geom_sankey_bump(
    width = 0.3,     
    color = "black"  
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = farben) + 
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),
    legend.position = "right",  
    legend.title = element_blank(),  
    legend.text = element_text(size = 10)  
  )

Any help is appreciated!

Here is one option which first infers the desired order from the data and uses the breaks= argument of scale_fill_manual to set the order in the legend. Also note that I make farben a named vector to keep the original assignment of colors to names.
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsankey)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

# Keep the original assignment of colors
names(farben) <- sort(unique(data_sankey$next_id))

legend_order <- data_sankey |>
  dplyr::filter(Year == max(Year)) |>
  arrange(desc(value)) |>
  pull(next_id)

p <- ggplot(data_sankey, aes(
  x = id,
  next_x = next_id,
  node = next_id,
  fill = next_id,
  value = value
)) +
  geom_sankey_bump(
    color = "black"
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = farben,
    breaks = legend_order
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),
    legend.position = "right",
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 10)
  ) 
p


EDIT And to add some labels to the final nodes you can do:
p +
  geom_sankey_text(
    aes(
      label = ifelse(Year == max(Year), value, NA),
      next_node = next_id
    ),
    na.rm = TRUE,
    hjust = -.1,
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")



Stefan, thank you! This helped a lot. Do you know how to add a geom_(sankey_?)text for Year == max(Year) as well? Can't figure this out either.

See my update on how to add labels to the final nodes.
